# Install Old version of hive with brew

Tags: linux, unix, hive

When i do a

```
brew install hive
```

i am installing 1.1.1 . Is there a way to install old versions of hive like 1.0.1 using brew or install hive using brew from a URL.

Comment: SO is meant for programming questions, this question belongs on superuser.com.